# collapse and paste text by multiple grouping sequential variables

Tags: r, data.table

I have rows with grouping variables and text.  I want to use **data.table** to paste the text when grouping variables are all the same for n times in a row.

Here's what I have:

```
       x y                              z
 1:  Pre A Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ac
 2:  Pre C Maecenas netus in, lacus fames
 3:  Pre C Conubia sed nulla dolor dui ap
 4:  Pre A Eget laoreet eros in aliquet e
 5:  Pre A Vestibulum quisque himenaeos p
 6: Post A Sed venenatis. Ante turpis ege
 7: Post A Ultricies ultricies eleifend m
 8: Post B Conubia in in sed etiam nec mo
 9: Post A Quam nec ex sodales dictum orc
10: Post A Sed ante id pulvinar maximus s
```

Desired output:

```
     x y                                                             z
1  Pre A                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ac
2  Pre C Maecenas netus in, lacus fames Conubia sed nulla dolor dui ap
3  Pre A Eget laoreet eros in aliquet e Vestibulum quisque himenaeos p
4 Post A Sed venenatis. Ante turpis ege Ultricies ultricies eleifend m
5 Post B                                Conubia in in sed etiam nec mo
6 Post A Quam nec ex sodales dictum orc Sed ante id pulvinar maximus s
```

MWE:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

set.seed(12)
dat <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c("Pre", "Post"), each=5), 
    y = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, TRUE), 
    z = substring(stri_rand_lipsum(10), 1, 30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

setDT(dat)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could use `rleid` from the devel version of `data.table` to create the grouping variable ('gr') based on the 'x' and 'y' variables.  Grouped by 'gr', we get the first element of 'x', 'y', and `paste` the 'z' elements together.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(dat)[,list(x=x[1L], y= y[1L], z=paste(z, collapse = ' ')) ,
                      by = .(gr=rleid(x,y))][, gr:= NULL][]
#      x y                                                             z
#1:  Pre A                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ac
#2:  Pre C Maecenas netus in, lacus fames Conubia sed nulla dolor dui ap
#3:  Pre A Eget laoreet eros in aliquet e Vestibulum quisque himenaeos p
#4: Post A Sed venenatis. Ante turpis ege Ultricies ultricies eleifend m
#5: Post B                                Conubia in in sed etiam nec mo
#6: Post A Quam nec ex sodales dictum orc Sed ante id pulvinar maximus s
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

---

Another option if we are not using the devel version would be to create the 'gr' variable by comparing the adjacent elements after `paste`ing 'x' and 'y' columns and then proceed as before.

```
setDT(dat)[, gr:={gr= paste(x,y); cumsum(c(TRUE, gr[-1]!= gr[-.N]))}]
res <- dat[, list(x=x[1L], y=y[1L], z=paste(z, collapse=' ')) ,
                     by = gr][,gr:= NULL][]
res
#      x y                                                             z
#1:  Pre A                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ac
#2:  Pre C Maecenas netus in, lacus fames Conubia sed nulla dolor dui ap
#3:  Pre A Eget laoreet eros in aliquet e Vestibulum quisque himenaeos p
#4: Post A Sed venenatis. Ante turpis ege Ultricies ultricies eleifend m
#5: Post B                                Conubia in in sed etiam nec mo
#6: Post A Quam nec ex sodales dictum orc Sed ante id pulvinar maximus s
```

This also assigns the 'gr' column in the original dataset.  We can assign the 'gr' to `NULL` to keep the original structure the same.

```
dat[, gr:= NULL]
```

Instead of doing `x=x[1L], y= y[1L]`, we can use 'x', 'y' and 'gr' as the grouping variables and return only the 'z' column.

```
res <- dat[,list(z=paste(z, collapse=' ')) ,.(x, y, gr)][, gr:= NULL][]
dat[, gr:= NULL]
```

Comment: Nice answer. `gr` is not removed from `dat` in the second option, though.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, didn't notice it.  Removed the  `gr` by assigning to NULL.